# adding data to schema optionally in mongodb using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I made a 2 mongodb schema in which one is depend on another schema and my both look like this

ownerSchema.js

```
var ownerSchema = Schema({
    ownerId   : String,
    fname     : String,
    lname     : String,
    shopPlace : { 
                  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                  ref: 'Shop'
                },
    shopType    String
});
var Owner = mongoose.model('Owner', ownerSchema);
```

shopSchema.js

```
var shopSchema = Schema({
    _id       : String,
    shopName  : String,
    location  : String,
    startDate : Date,
    endDate   : Date
});
var Shop  = mongoose.model('Shop', shopSchema);
```

and this is my add function

```
const addOwner = async (req, res) => {
 
    const { shopName, shopLocation } = req.body.shopPlace;
    const shop = new Shop({
      shopName,
      shopLocation,
    });
    await shop.save();

    const { ownerId, fname, lname } = req.body;
    const newOwner = new Owner({
      ownerId,
      fname,
      lname,
      shopPlace: shop._id,
    });
    await newOwner.save();
};
```

Problem is sometimes i dont want shopPlace data it should be blank

but I am sending  only ownerId, fname, lname from postman it does not saving in my database is there any possible way that if I dont want shopPlace still it should save data to my schema it should be optional

Comment: so you want shopPlace data to get saved or dont want it to be saved?

Comment: it should be saved but it should be optional @itiDi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model you can set a default value for `shopPlace` as follows:

```
shopPlace : { 
   type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   ref: 'Shop',
   default: null
}
```

So, if you don't provide `shopPlace` when you create a new `Owner`, it will be `null`

Comment: its showing `Cannot destructure property 'shopName' of 'undefined' or 'null'."`

Comment: It is because you don't provide `shopPlace` in your request. You can add a condition to check if `req.body.shopPlace` exists then create a new `Shop`. And when you create a new `Owner` down below, you can short circuit `shopPlace` property: `shopPlace: shop && shop._id`

Comment: i have made an if condition to check `if (req.body.shopPlace){  const { shopName, shopLocation } = req.body.shopPlace;
    const shop = new Shop({
      shopName,
      shopLocation,
    });
    await shop.save();` but it still not working

Comment: Oh, great, happy to help :)